# Catch all error cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp

I using cakephp, when  have error, cakephp show error for users example : undefine index, notice in view page...I want when have error cakephp just show one message customize by me in view. Someone know ? Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom error pages,

/app/Config/core.php

Exception render need to set as an AppExceptionRender. Example:

> Configure::write('Exception', array(
>           'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
>           'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer',
>           'log' => true ));

/app/Controller/ErrorsController.php

> class ErrorsController extends AppController {
>       public $name = 'Errors';
>
> ```
> public function beforeFilter() {
>     parent::beforeFilter();
>     $this->Auth->allow('error404');
> }
>
> public function error404() {
>     //$this->layout = 'default';
> } }
> ```

/app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php

App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

> class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
>
> ```
> public function notFound($error) {
>     $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'error404'));
> } }
> ```

/app/View/Errors/error404.ctp

> `enter code here`
>
> ### 404 Error - Page Not Found
>
> `enter code here`

Insert it where you need: throw new NotFoundException();

after that make sure debug mode is 0,
Its work with production mode only
Configure::write('debug', 0);